# MSSQL - disable metadata in query result

Tags: sql-server, oledb

We are using a MSSQL 15 database for our application. Access to the database is established using OLEDB.
While running a series of 10,000 queries

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE primary_key = "some_id"
```

we experienced a rather large drop in performance (factor of around 10) when we switched from running the application directly on the database server to running it on another machine that connects to the server via TCP/IP.

We then investigated the packets sent to and from the server using wireshark. We found that the server replied to every `SELECT` with the metadata (fieldname, datatype, etc.) of every field of the result followed by the single row of data we had selected. We do not need the metadata information as we already know the structure of table we run the query on.
Because the metadata block is much larger than the actual data, most of the data sent through the network are (to us) completely redundant.

Is there any way to tell the server not to include the metadata in the query result?

Comment: The short answer is no - you can't disable this. The slightly longer answer is that your approach of executing 10k individual queries is the problem - don't do that. At a minimum use a query to retrieve a reasonably sized batch of rows.

Comment: Have you considered ways to send your 10,000 `some_id` values to SQL in a single query? Perhaps look into using table-valued parameters to stored procedures, or JSON or XML.

Comment: Why on earth would you run 10k identical queries in the first place? SQL likes sets, just batch it up in a temp table or TVP